# Apache Beam DirectRunner vs FlinkRunner example

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

i've built the simplest pipeline using beam yaml (python sdk) where a csv file is read and should be printed to log.
while running with default DirectRunner:

```
python -m apache_beam.yaml.main --pipeline_spec_file=pipeline-01.yaml
```

everything works fine and i do see the output, however when using FlinkRunner:

```
python -m apache_beam.yaml.main --pipeline_spec_file=pipeline-01.yaml --runner=FlinkRunner --flink_version=1.16 --flink_master=localhost:8081 --environment_type=EXTERNAL --environment_config=localhost:50000
```

no logs are printed, even though i can see through the Flink Dashboard that the run succeeded.

my pipeline:

```
pipeline:
  type: chain
  transforms:
    - type: ReadFromCsv
      config:
        path: data/input2.csv
    - type: LogForTesting
```

the path is to a file stored locally on my computer.

can anyone clarify?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you look for the output? Finding the Flink logs where the output appears can be tricky.

Comment: @DavidAnderson when using the direct runner the log is actually printed as a part of the pipeline's run. however i also checked task managers & job manager pods, no sign of any log message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was quite embarrassing..

my pipeline was looking at a file saved locally, but i forgot to copy it into flink cluster (so basically, there were no logs because the file was "empty" when running with FlinkRunner.
Once file was copied it worked great :)